# INSERT INTO issue with python + tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter based revision application which has a variety of learning options, such as flashcards and an exam-style questions simulator. For the exam questions, each question the user gets right, a new score and a timestamp will be added to a SQLite database called "scores", namely in the columns INT "phy" and DATETIME "phystamp". The score gets updated by adding 20 to the previous record in the "phy", and adding the timestamp of it in the same row in the "phystamp" column. However this program doesn't seem to work, as the record is not appeared to have been successfully inserted into the database. Im getting no errors while running the code.

Any other ways of structuring my code will also help as i've only recently starting coding with python and SQL.

```
        if realanswer == data[randomphysics][2]:
            cursor.execute("""SELECT phy FROM scores WHERE phy=(SELECT max(phy) FROM scores)""")
            lastrecord = cursor.fetchone()
            num = int(''.join(map(str, lastrecord)))
            newrecord = num + 20
            dt = datetime.now()
            physicstime = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            decisionlabel.config(text="Correct Answer!")
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores(phy,phystamp)VALUES(?,?)",(newrecord,physicstime))
            print(physicstime)

        else:
            decisionlabel.config(text=f"Incorrect Answer! The correct answer is {data[randomphysics][2]}")
```

Comment: What exactly happens (or doesn't happen)?

Comment: Actually you don't need the SELECT statement, just one INSERT is enough: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO scores (phy, phystamp) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(phy)+20 FROM scores), STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))")`.

Comment: 1) I am not seeing anything along lines of `connection.commit()`. Without that the data will not be saved to database. If that is not the issue then you will need to add to the question a more specific explanation of what is not working. 2) Not seeing how this has anything to do with CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you write an insert-statement SQLite will implicitly open a transaction, which you explicitly need to close to make changes to the database. so just follow up your cursor.execute(...) with a connection.commit().